# Wrap an HTML structure around text using jquery

Tags: jquery

I was trying to wrap a Achor tag to the Email-id dynamically, I am facing issues below is my html code:

```
<tr>
  <td id='label'>
    email
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      abc@gmail.com
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and jquery code which i am trying is wraping the Achor tag to the div :

```
$("tr td#label:contains('email')").next().each(function(){ 

   $(this).wrapInner('<a href="mailto:'+$(this).text()+'">');

});
```

i what to wrap a Achor tag to Email-Id. how can i do this?

Comment: Should that not be $("#label:contains('email')").next("div").. the ID is supposed to be unique

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YXUmr/)

Comment: but the Achor tag is above the div.

Answer (score 1):

First modify markup to use `class` insted of `id` :

```
<tr>
  <td class='label'>
    email
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
      abc@gmail.com
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Script:

```
$(".label:contains('email')").each(function(){
    var email = $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('div').text();
    $(this).html('<a href="mailto:'+email+'">email</a>');
});
```